# FCM Token is not generating for the 1st time, generates after 2nd time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("TOKEN_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String token = prefs.getString("token", "");
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.this);
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        String genToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("TOKEN_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("token", genToken);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Token error : "+task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

The above code is where used it when the user login to the account so that i generate the token and store it in to database based on the user id during the login process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this method and check

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

// If you want to send messages to this application instance or
// manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
// Instance ID token to your app server.
sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}
```